# Set an RGB color value as default in My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, colors, default, my.settings

VB2010. I have setup some settings in MyProject.Settings. One of them being being a color variable. However I cant seem to figure out how I can set a specific RGB value as the default. The My.Settings designer only lets you pick predetermined colors. How can I set the default to be RGB(214, 133, 137).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click in there and type in your desired value!
[image]

Comment: Note: You can find out the correct format for the value string by picking a "custom" color from the color picker dialog you get in the drop-down menu.
This is relevant, because (at least in VS 2010) with the German locale, the RGB values must be separated by semicolons instead of commas: 214; 133; 137